# What folder in Windows everyone or IIS User has access to read and write?

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions

Recently i start develop a setup program using asp.net , I want to save some global information on server machine . Registry is a way but IIS User default not write permission.
So i think some folders such as "Application Data" can do it,but everyone did not write Permissions.Is there other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The temporary folder: `%TEMP%`. If it is an ASP.NET application you could also use the special [App_Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fb46ye(VS.80).aspx) folder.

Comment: App_Data can not meet my needs,because i need a container save global information and any other program can read it

Comment: Depends on how you've set up your app pool identity - by default the IUSR/IIS Worker Process accounts don't have access to the systems temp folder, they use the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` directory under the `Microsoft.NET\Framework\vX.Y.Z\` folder.

Comment: @Zhaph - Ben Duguid,Thank you!!the Temporary ASP.NET Files directory is my need,thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Any directory which has permissions set to everyone access. Please check this link http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/using/networking/security/permissions.mspx

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to figure the temp paths out for yourself. Please use the [System.IO.Path.GetTempPath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx) method.